# How to take the lower value from webpage with Selenium + Java?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, web-testing

sorry for stupid question. I`m new at selenium with Java and trying to learn it.
I have 4 price values on the page and should choose the lower one and memorize it.
I tryed .getText() but it not working as I expected.
Could you please help me?

[Xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQxYZ.jpg)

[Prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHmxa.jpg)

Comment: What exactly did you try and what exactly "not working as I expected"?

Comment: Can you share URL with us if it's public ?

Comment: https://www.ryanair.com/ - URL is public, I use it to learn.

Comment: I don`t know how to explain better. 
I want to write a script that will select the cheapest ticket on the page and display the price. Direction is not important.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code-writing service. Someone may be willing to put in the time to solve this for you (and it might be me if I get bored later) but you will get better results if you post your code attempts and describe exactly how it's not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your quesion is not sharp enouth.

In general the way would be:

- Select the all prices via xpath
- put them into an integer list
- use Java streams in order to get the lowest value